# Pharmacokinetics question was closed and I'd like it re-opened

Tags: support, close-reasons, closed-questions, re-open

I asked a [pharmacokinetics question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/110768/ways-to-increase-the-bioavailability-of-myo-inositol-using-a-carrier-compound) in the stackexchange which another user decided to close. I believe this was unreasonable and request that the question be reopened. The question was regarding how gelatin increased the solubility of myo-inositol, a slightly water-soluble aromatic sugar alcohol, and what other substances could do the same. I also wanted to know what this mechanism is actually called, as I was referring to the gelatin as a "carrier compound", which I doubt is the correct term.

The user who closed my question decided that since I was asking the question to assist in my supplementation, the question had no intellectual value and should be closed. The thing is though that myo-inositol is GRAS and if you decided to eat an absurd quantity, you'd get diarrhea and wouldn't be able to absorb it anyways. So overdosing on it isn't really physically possible and thus shouldn't be a concern. Also, this question being answered would have no effect on how much myo-inositol I'd be taking anyways as I'd only be switching from gelatin to another "carrier compound".

I've noticed this stackexchange has no questions(other than mine) regarding how softgel capsules(the gelatin component specifically) increase the bioavailability of various compounds, despite this being an extremely important thing in pharmacology. I feel that discarding my question in its entirety is doing this stackexchange a major disservice. Is there an edit I could make to my post so that it would be acceptable?

Answer (score 6):

No, we are not going to accept your personal medical advice question.

Do not seek this information elsewhere or attempt to circumvent these restrictions here, the rules are rules for reason of safety.

Comment: @Laff70 Is it so difficult to appreciate that 1) You aren't entitled to answers here just because you have a question. 2) Rules against medical advice are meant to protect people. We can't and won't do anything to verify that the people answering have any sort of credentials that qualify them to answer. Rather than being entitled jerks who decide which medical questions are safe to ask and which are not, we just say they aren't allowed to make the rule clear.

Comment: 1. Of course I know I'm not entitled to an answer. This is stackexchange, where well written questions oftentimes go to collect dust because no one with sufficient expertise in the relevant matter saw it in time.
2. You literally said “Do not seek this information elsewhere or attempt to circumvent these restrictions here”. By doing so you were acting like you somehow possessed the authority to stop me from/punish me for doing so. I’d say that goes well beyond merely not allowing such questions to be asked. Also, if this is the case, you guys should’ve instead asked me to edit my [1/3]

Comment: my question so the medical advice aspect of it went away. Instead, you did your typical stackexchange kneejerk reaction of closing the question whilst attacking the poster for seeking recourse. What you *should’ve* done was had me rewrite my question so I was instead asking how gelatin functions as a “carrier compound“, what the technical term for “carrier compound“ is, and what other “carrier compound“’s would increase the solubility of molecules like myo-inositol. If you did that, biology.stackexchange would info regarding the pharmacokinetics involved in drug making, like kneaded [2/3]

Comment: mixtures. Info which I’ve stated the site is currently lacking despite its importance. Instead, you’ve decided to deprive biology.stackexchange of this information. You’ve handled this terribly. [3/3]

Comment: My warning not to seek an answer elsewhere is because designing and taking your own supplements this way is quite dangerous. No, it's absolutely not wrong to close a question in this circumstance, questions should be closed if they can't be answered in their current form, because that's what closure does: it prevents answers. If a question can be fixed, the order is close, fix, reopen, such that answers can come only after the fix. Your question shouldn't be rewritten or revised, though.

Comment: It's a sugar alcohol and gelatin... It's not dangerous. I'm literally just dissolving gelatin in warm water, mixing in myo-inositol, and drinking it. That's it. By your logic, no one should be allowed to have tools like knives because they might accidentally cut themselves while making food. This approach to safety is excessive and debilitating. I see now that this stackexchange isn't a place of learning, but of coddled ignorance. This stackexchange needs new management.

Comment: Think of it as you like, but we are not going to change this rule, as it is there for a reason.

Comment: @Laff70 - Have you ever heard of a a logical fallacy called an *ad hominem*? It goes like this: *Stack Exchange closed my important question. What a bunch of jerks they are.* Attack the policy (ideally with a convincing *arguement* - hence logic) instead of attacking the characters of users. (Well, only if you want to be taken seriously, that is.)

Comment: If you wanted to know how softgel capsules, specifically the gelatin component, increases the bioavailability of various compounds, and added some research of your own, I probably would have answered it, as it's a decent and (to me) interesting question.